# Explain plan final cost doesn't match cost of each step

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to performance tune a query and everything in my explain plan has a very low cost. I'm using Materialized Views and proper indices but the plans final cost is 239,925 where everything else is between 0-69. What am I missing? I have partitioned large mvs, parallelism and indices.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry about the pictures but I'm not sure of another way to export the explain plan.

The code looks like this:

```
       UPDATE KC_TEST_REPORT_2 rep 
        SET    (    department, 
                    documenttype, 
                    orgfunction, 
                    risklevel, 
                    assetcriticality, 
                    cft 
                ) = ( 
        SELECT
                    dept.valstr Department, 
                    doctype.valstr DocumentType, 
                    orgFunc.valstr OrgFunction, 
                    risk.valstr    RiskLevel, 
                    crit.valstr    AssetCriticality, 
                    cft.valstr     CFT 
        FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 dept 
                left outer join MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 doctype 
                            ON doctype.defid = 3070055 
                            AND doctype.attrid = 6 
                            AND doctype.vernum = dept.vernum 
                            AND  doctype.defvern = dept.defvern 

                left outer join MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 orgFunc 
                            ON orgFunc.defid = 3070055 
                            AND orgFunc.attrid = 2 
                            AND orgFunc.vernum = dept.vernum 
                            AND orgFunc.defvern = dept.defvern 

                left outer join MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 risk 
                            on risk.defid=3070055 
                            and risk.attrid = 20 
                            AND risk.vernum = dept.vernum 
                            AND risk.defvern = dept.defvern 

                left outer join MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 crit 
                            ON crit.defid = 3070055 
                            AND crit.attrid = 24 
                            AND crit.vernum = dept.vernum 
                            AND crit.defvern = dept.defvern 

                left outer join MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 cft 
                            ON cft.defid = 3070055 
                            AND cft.attrid = 23 
                            AND cft.vernum = dept.vernum 
                            AND cft.defvern = dept.defvern 

        WHERE  dept.id = rep.dataid 
                AND dept.defid = 3070055 
                AND dept.attrid = 4 
                AND doctype.id = rep.dataid 
                AND orgFunc.id = rep.dataid 
                AND orgFunc.entrynum = 1 
                AND risk.id = rep.dataid 
                AND crit.id = rep.dataid 
                AND cft.id = rep.dataid 
                AND dept.vernum =  (SELECT MV.vernum
                                    FROM   MV_LLATTRBLOBDATA_VERNNUM_V1 MV 
                                    WHERE  id = rep.dataid) 
                AND dept.defvern = (SELECT MV.MAX_DEFVERN
                                    FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                                    WHERE id = rep.dataid 
                                        AND defid = 3070055 
                                        AND attrid = 4));
```

Comment: To get a text-based execution plan run `explain plan for select ...;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to tune a query. The cost column is not a measurement of the cost of your query. It's used internally to compare between the many different plans the optimizer came up with to make its decision as to which one is best.

Instead, what you should be doing is looking at an execution plan, at the actual time for each step, the estimated rows vs. the actual rows, and maybe seeing if there are some missing indexes or something.

You might want to refer to the [Database Performance Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i16938).

Comment: Based on the explain plan posted though, I don't see anything that stands out. The database is currently disconnected from a front-end system, meaning the data does not change at all. We've run table, index, and schema stats. We're using Materialized views that are partitioned, indexed and paralleled, not compressed (considering compression) and yet we still get reports taking 5-20 minutes.

Comment: I would run an execution plan will will give you timings for each step and the number of rows involved.